# Changing the open with settings in 10.10.1

Tags: finder, macos, numbers, plist

I am looking for a way to edit the open with settings in 10.10.1, i have looked through older questions and have attempted to rename the launch services plist and have gotten no where.

I have looked through the

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister`

and my

`/Users/J/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist`

and I was able to remove text edit from random extensions but i am still unable to remove numbers or find its assoisation to .py files in a

`/lsregister -dump`

Here is a picture to clarify, i would like to remove numbers.app and pages.app along with xcode.app as options to open up files with a .py extension.

[image]

Sidenote: Another related feature is i would like to add an application in that menu for every single file type in my system. For example i would like to be able to open every file in my system with hexfiend and textedit.

right clicking/adding every time i have a new file type is a pain because my applications folder is filled with a few apps that are folders that get searched recursively when i look through it

Update: solution directly from apple -- Uninstall numbers.
Other then uninstalling the application, it is not possible to remove applications from this list published by apple... any other publisher and it is possible lol.......

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Request a mod to migrate if you think you posted to the wrong one - http://superuser.com/questions/855195/changing-the-open-with-settings-in-10-10-1

Comment: [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) can change defaults, but idk how to remove unwanted apps from the list

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry initially posted it on stackoverflow then was sent from there to superuser to apple, forgot to delete superuser. RCDefault does look useful but it seems a bit buggy and i can not find where it associated numbers to .py

Comment: No worries, just thought I'd mention it;) Me neither - numbers doesn't show that it ought to be associated with .py, but it is on my machine too.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah it is starting to get annoying with so many other file types having 100% useless associations. a different thing that would be slightly helpful would be to say add one application to that list for every single file type on the system, updated question with a sidenote/ explination

Comment: confirmed resetting LaunchServices doesn't clear it - it didn't annoy me before you mentioned it, but now it does ;-) I did find this to add an "Open With [specific app]" to Services - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151201/fetching-behavior-in-finder-open-with-menu-in-yosemite

Comment: I also found this - but it doesn't work for Pages & Numbers, might be good for others, though - http://mac-how-to.wonderhowto.com/how-to/remove-duplicates-customize-open-with-menu-mac-os-x-0157100/

Comment: @Tetsujin nice link at wonderhow, it does look like it was written on 10.9 though so maybe its outdated which is why it still will not work for numbers?

Comment: I'm still on 10.9 & it doesn't work here either, it's just not in the plist… maybe .py is 'just text' as far as they are concerned, which of course, they are perfectly capable of opening?

Comment: @Tetsujin maybe but doesn't .py have a different associated uti then .txt? at least its different in the /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -dump .   and err now i kinda want to remove numbers from .txt to lol, i mean this just seems like something that should be customizable

Comment: Association & generic capability don't seem to be separated at OS level