# Finder doesn't show "Open With" menu, just "Fetching..."

Tags: finder

When I rightclick a file in Finder and hover over "Open With" (e.g. I have .mp3 files associated with VLC but sometimes want to open them with Audacity or iTunes, and then use "Open With"; or want to use LibreOffice for a spreadsheet file instead of Numbers), the "Open With" menu doesn't open and just shows, greyed-out: "Fetching..." and the menu with different apps doesn't appear, even when I wait for minutes. How can this be fixed?

P.S. I searched for previous posts about this problem and could only find ["Fetching..." Behavior in Finder "Open With" Menu in Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151201/fetching-behavior-in-finder-open-with-menu-in-yosemite) but that is more about Finder taking a few seconds delay for the pop-up menu to appear, while mine doesn't appear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be time to rebuild your LaunchServices database.
You will need to reset any custom associations.

The simplest method to do this is using [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) (freeware).

Maintenance tab/Rebuilding

[image]